# Using CSS to Swap Out Images and Text (Pictures Included)

Tags: html, css, hover, image-replacement, replace

Alrighty guys, I got myself in over my head at my internship. Even my Computer Theory professor, who is an ex-department head from Wolfram Alpha isn't really giving me any useful information. It appears I must embark on building this set of web pages with only your guidance, as I can't find any sites that are of much use elsewhere.

I'm putting together pages that explain different technologies we have integrated into a classroom environment. I want to use a CSS Image Gallery, [kind of like this](http://host.sonspring.com/hoverbox/), in the sense that when you hover over an image, a larger one pops up.

However, I want it to be able to swap out an image and accompanying text and links within an iframe. [Here's an illustration of what I mean.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RVEXQ.jpg) When the mouse hovers over one of the pictures in the left-hand gallery, I'd like the image, the text underneath it, and the information in the text box to the left of it to change. My idea is to present all the information necessary within the iframe, so that you get everything relating to that piece of tech in one place.

The box under "Podium Components" would be the iframe. I know the swapping of the image can be done via CSS, since I built a website utilizing it for my Web Development class (Wolfram Alpha teacher :D)

If it's possible, I'd like to avoid Java or JavaScript for this one and stick to pure CSS. The CMS we're using for the website is Drupal, so things are already pretty complicated. Throwing JavaScript into the mix will just make things too wacky.

As an added note, I always feel guilty using StackOverflow when I'm working on projects. It feels like I'm cheating :/. So I'd really appreciate it if you could just point me toward a tutorial or tell me search terms that will get me where I need to go. Help me teach myself so I can be more marketable? :D Thanks in advance, guys!

Comment: Because that's what's used elsewhere on our website. I'm aiming for consistency since it's not my build, I'm just helping the group I'm interning for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really want to do this without javascript (I don't think there's anything wacky about it nowadays) you could put your "podium components" in invisible `<div>` elements and place them inside each item in your left-hand gallery. Kind of like this:

```
<ul id="gallery">
    <li id="item1">
        Left-hand item 1
        <div class="hidden-data">
            Your podium component's content here
        </div>
    </li>
    <li id="item2">
        Left-hand item 2
        <div class="hidden-data">
            Another podium component
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Now you can create a `:hover` style for the list items to make them visible only when the mouse is over it. You won't need an `<iframe>` for this solution and I think it would be more optimal, except if you have a huge amount of items in your left-hand gallery.

Placing the podium components to the right where you want them could be done by setting their `position` as `absolute`. I'll leave it to you to find out how they work (hint: you'll need to set a parent element as `position: relative` - but not just any parent element, choose wisely!) :)

**Edit**: [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/GX4Nn/) is a spoiler if you want to see it in action.

Comment: So I'd have it set up so all of the different hidden data is nested within each item of the gallery... Then have the box off to the right pull say, item1.hidden-data?

Comment: Correct, except the box to the right won't have to pull anything, if you position the hidden data correctly. Try positioning them without hiding them first, they should all get stacked in the same place in the top right corner.

Comment: Below is what I have for code in the CSS. I tried to model it after the way I have text show up underneath the pictures on the right (the description of the picture) but it just shows up under the thumbnail on the left. Any ideas?

#desertHiddenData a:hover hidden-data {display: block;
position: absolute; 
text-align: center;}

Comment: Actually looking at it now, the code you provided is making it show up.
    <li><a href="Desert.jpg"><img src="Desert.jpg" width="100" height="75" alt="Desert">
    <span><img src="Desert.jpg" width="500" height="400" alt="Desert"><br>Cool looking desert with a lot of rocks.</span></a>
    <div id="desertHiddenData" class="hidden_data">
    <p>Deserts are very dangerous. Don't wander through them alone unless    you're prepared.</p>
    </div>
    </li>

Comment: Henry: Try adding right: 0; top: 0; to your rules. If it shows up in the wrong place, set one of the parent elements to position: relative - absolutely positioned elements get positioned relative to the closest relatively positioned ancestor.

Comment: @HenryEdwardQuinnIV: I added a fiddle to my answer, check it out if you don't mind being spoiled.

Comment: Thank you SO much for that! However, the project's evolved since this morning. The boss-man wants users to be able to click on a picture, and have all the information stay there. I'm playing with some JavaScript and trying to learn onclicks.

Comment: No problem! You _could_ do that too in pure CSS with delayed transitions but you can get a much cleaner and less gimmicky result by using JS.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11110/discussion-between-henry-edward-quinn-iv-and-kaivosukeltaja)

Answer (score 1):

If you only want to use CSS for the sake of using CSS, that's a wrong approach regarding semantics of web-development. But for the sake of not being an ass, I'll try and help! ;)

You could use the CSS property 'content' to change content in DIV's and such, without using something like JavaScript to do so:
http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_gen_content.asp The benefit of this solution is that you wouldn't need to create iframes for content you want to change.

Of course, there are other solutions, if you insist on using iframes. You could also use CSS's pseudo-classes on an image's hover state to change the display value of an iframe.

http://devsnippets.com/article/5-advanced-css-pseudo-class.html

As in, hovering on an image enlarges the image, and changes the content of a DIV simultaneously. I believe that shouldn't be so hard!

I hope this helped a little!

Comment: I know that's the wrong approach for web development, I just don't have a very large skill set yet! I don't insist on using iframes, I'm still learning all the ins and outs of development, so I'll look into the content property and see what's what. Thank you SO much, Robin.

Comment: Thanks! I was just asking because this would be a lot easier using a little JavaScript magic! Cheers!

Comment: I don't know enough Java to be able to figure that out quickly enough. Happen to have a resource for what I'm trying to do right off the top of your head? If not, I don't want to bother you with looking for it.

Comment: Maybe something like this: http://www.codingforums.com/showthread.php?t=55413 But I can't think of a pack that would do it.

Comment: Robin, you're a saint. That's PERFECT.